# Modulus in Congruence

Tags: congruence-relations

I was proving a function to be onto but got stuck at point 
(7 mod 15) * (? mod 15) = 1 mod 15
I need some value at ? .So that I can get 1 mod 15.
Thank you very much . Every help is appreciated

Comment: You are looking for the *modular inverse* of $7 \bmod 15$.

Comment: What is your function? How about ?=13? $7\cdot 13=91=6\cdot 15+1$

Comment: You could use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to solve $7 x + 15 y = 1$, but a brute-force search won't take very long.

Comment: @Cornman Yes it really solved my problem , Thank you very  much.
I totally skipped this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the [*modular inverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $7\bmod 15$ to exist at all, you need $\gcd(7,15)=1$, which is true here.

Since $\color{red}{2}\cdot 7\equiv 14\equiv \color{red}{-1} \bmod 15$, you will have $\color{red}{-2}\cdot 7\equiv 1 \bmod 15$. And $-2\equiv 13\bmod 15$.